# Looping through JSON in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
var resobj = {
    "status": {
        "code": 2000,
        "message": "Success"
    },
    "order": {
        "Shop": 1,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Customer": 1 
    }
}
```

I have this json and I need to loop through the order and access the keys(shop,quantity,customer).Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: what do you mean by loop through? In order to loop through you should have an order array

Comment: *loop through the order* I can see only one order node, looping indicates that there are multiple of them.

Comment: For your case, you will have to do `for(var key in resobj.order)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Object#keys will return you the array of keys

```js
var resobj = {
    "status": {
        "code": 2000,
        "message": "Success"
    },
    "order": {
        "Shop": 1,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Customer": 1 
    }
};

Object.keys(resobj.order).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `Object.keys` [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)]

Example:

```
Object.keys(resobj.order).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key);
});
// Will log the keys "Shop", "Quantity" and "Customer"
```